# ListView tools:listitem not working in android studio 2.2 stable channel

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Open Layout editor
- Add a ListItem
- Specify tools:listitem property with a valid row_layout

**What should happen:**

It should use the layout from tools:listitem to render list items.

**Actual result:**

Nothing changes, it still shows the default list with generic views

**Bug Report**

I could see this bug was already filed on Jul 5, 2016 [Bug Report Link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215172&can=1&q=-has%3Adevpreview%20attachments%3D0%20component%3DTools&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=7500)

Are there any work around available to render list?

Comment: I've seen the same issue in my project. I made some changes to my item layout and then changed the value of 'tools:listitem' in my 'RecyclerView' to another item and then back to the correct one, while checking the design preview in between. It seems to work now.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann thanks for the update it might help the developer who are using RecyclerView. I am using listview and tried your approach but didn't worked for me.

Comment: Android Studio 3.3.2 Still this issue is present

Comment: But works for Listview not for android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Answer (score 7):

One thing to notice: it's `tools:listitem` not `tools:listItem` which is somewhat confusing. Took me some time to figure that out, since Android Studio currently doesn't provide autocompletion for that.

Answer (score 2):

You must define an id i.e. android:id="@+id/list_view" to your list

Comment: why downvote? our friend has said right. without id the listview doesn't show any item. i used an id for my list and the items has been shown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why `tools:listItem` doesn't work is when you're using the AndroidX's RecyclerView when using an older Android Studio. Update to 3.2 or higher and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Android Studio 2.3 beta 1

Comment: would be great if you'd link to bugtracker or changelog

Comment: The bug is still open and I see no reference to it in the changelog. However, I've tried it myself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

**File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart**

fixed the issue for me